# `id` column not found. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in php

Tags: php, json, on-duplicate-key

I used the JSON file records to insert to the MySQL database using PHP script. The following is the JSON file which contains the table name, field names, and values with more than 25 tables.

```
[
  {
    "tableName": "cashdrawer_open_time",
    "rows": []
  },
  {
    "tableName": "counters",
    "rows": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "B",
        "description": "SAKTHY",
        "added_on": "2018-06-21T12:49:30",
        "last_updated": "2018-02-18T12:49:40",
        "department": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "E",
        "description": "SAKTHY2",
        "added_on": "2018-06-21T12:50:21",
        "last_updated": "2018-06-21T14:52:18",
        "department": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The following PHP script(Thank you @Sloan Thrasher) is used to insert the JSON file records to the tables which are in online. But when I execute this script, I got the following error echo's in the browser.

```
<?php
try
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "fmart", "password", "fmart_dbsync"); 
    $query = '';
    $table_data = '';
    $filename = "sample.json";

    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $array = json_decode($data, true); 

    foreach($array as $set) 
    {
        $tblName = $set['tableName'];
        if(sizeof($set['rows']) > 0) 
        {
            $query = '';
            $colList = array();
            $valList = array();
            //  Get list of column names
            foreach($set['rows'][0] as $colName => $dataval) 
            {
                $colList[] = "`".$colName."`";
            }
            $query .= "INSERT INTO `".$tblName."` \n";
            $query .= "(".implode(",",$colList).")\nVALUES\n";
            //  Go through the rows for this table.
            foreach($set['rows'] as $idx => $row) 
            {
                $colDataA = array();
                //  Get the data values for this row.
                foreach($row as $colName => $colData) 
                {
                    $colDataA[] = "'".$colData."'";
                }
                $valList[] = "(".implode(",",$colDataA).")";
            }
            //  Add values to the query.
            $query .= implode(",\n",$valList)."\n";
            //  If id column present, add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause
            if(in_array("id", $colList)) 
            {
                $query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\t SET ";
                $tmp = array();
                foreach($colList as $idx => $colName) 
                {
                    //$tmp[] = $colName." = new.".$colName." ";
                    $tmp[] = $colName." = VALUE(".$colName.") ";    //  Changed this line to get value from current insert row data

                }
                $query .= implode(",",$tmp)."\n";
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "<p><b>`id`</b> column not found. <i>ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE</i> clause <b>NOT</b> added.</p>\n";
                echo "<p>Columns Found:<pre>".print_r($colList, true)."</pre></p>\n";
            }
            echo "<p>Insert query:<pre>$query</pre></p>";
            $r = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
            echo "<h1>".mysqli_affected_rows($connect). " Rows appended in .$tblName.</h1>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<p>No rows to insert for .$tblName.</p>";
        }
    }
} 

catch(Exception $e)
{   
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

?>

The following is the error echo's printed on the browser when executing the PHP script:

```
No rows to insert for .bank_accounts.

No rows to insert for .bank_transactions.

No rows to insert for .cashdrawer_open_time.

`id` column not found. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause NOT added.

Columns Found:

Array
(
    [0] => `id`
    [1] => `name`
    [2] => `description`
    [3] => `added_on`
    [4] => `last_updated`
    [5] => `department`
)
Insert query:

.INSERT INTO `counters` 
(`id`,`name`,`description`,`added_on`,`last_updated`,`department`)
VALUES
('2','B','SAKTHY','2018-06-21T12:49:30','2018-02-18T12:49:40','1'),
('5','E','SAKTHY2','2018-06-21T12:50:21','2018-06-21T14:52:18','1')
.

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/fmart/public_html/newSync/webScript.php on line 60
Rows appended in .counters.

No rows to insert for .customer_transactions.

No rows to insert for .customers.

No rows to insert for .department_stock_transfers.

and so on...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some modification needed. You should use [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) instead of `mysqli_num_rows`. Because `mysqli_affected_rows` return rows affected by insert, update, delete queries. Try this modified code:

```
echo "<p>Insert query:<pre>.$query.</pre></p>";
if (mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
    echo "<h1>" . mysqli_affected_rows($connect) . " Rows appended in .$tblName.</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Query Failed</h1>";
}
```

Also update the line following:

```
$query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\t id = id + 1 ";
```

**Note:** I have updated only required part of code and other will remain same.

Comment: Thank you, I got it and going to check

Comment: after changed your code, I got the following errors : https://pastebin.com/0MD1J68J

Comment: Updated answer again!

Comment: As you told, I changed my original php script `mysqli_num_rows` into `mysqli_affected_rows` and the errors are : https://pastebin.com/wpDnp5pp (Updated)

Comment: Also need to change parameter given to `mysqli_affected_rows`. It should be what returned by `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: What parameter ? Now see this link https://pastebin.com/wpDnp5pp (updated) and changed php script as you told.

Comment: Yes see the link. `id` `2` is updated field and `id` `5`, `6` are newly inserted records. All of these are not inserted or updated to the online database.

Comment: Use `mysql_error` to check whether there is any error in query.

Comment: After query execution line.

Comment: It says `1062: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'` See the full echo's in the link : https://pastebin.com/wpDnp5pp (Updated).

Comment: `$query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\t id = id + 1 ";` does not successful